# UIButton title not showing when I setImage

Tags: ios, uibutton

The most common fix to this issue is "Set as background image, not normal image"

In my case I put background images on all my buttons, if it is a locked object, I add the image of a lock on top of the background image. The image looks as expected, but in that case it does not show the title of the image.

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
if(self.currentArray[index][2] != NULL) //before it was if (button == nil)
{
    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:self.currentArray[index][2]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.currentArray[index][5]];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    if ([self.currentArray[index][6] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        //show it
    }else{
//-------------------------        
//--THE PROBLEM HAPPENS IF THIS PIECE OF CODE IS EXECUTED, SPECIFICALLY setImage
//------------------------- 
        button.alpha = 0.5;
        UIImage *locked = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locked.png"];
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 15, 15, 15);
        [button setImage:locked forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 56, 56);
    button.tag = index;

    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIEdgeInsets buttonInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, -30, -25, -30);
    [button setTitleEdgeInsets:buttonInset];
    [button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 8];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Here is the images without lock and with lock:
[image]

Comment: Do the frames of the image and the title overlap?

Comment: no the image is normally 256x256 but after imageEdgeInsets its 1/4 of the background image and right in the middle.

Comment: You could also just add the text to the image with a photo editing program if you don't want to use mokagio's answer or don't need to modify the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918196/ios-interface-builder-uibutton-title-disappears-when-setting-image).

Quoting: "It appears that when you put an image in the button. the text is shoved off to the right. Use the edge settings to bring it back over the image."

What you have to do is play around with the title inset in order to bring the title label back to the right position.

I would suggest having something like an `extraLeftInset` variable that defaults to `0` and that is set to the right value in the `else` branch.

The answer above suggest to use this formula **[Edge inset for Title] Left = -(imageWidth * 2)**, so the value should be -512 since you say that the image normally is 256. It would be nicer to evaluate it at runtime inspecting the `size` of the image though.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the value that works is -256. btw the title has an alpha of 0.5. i added extra code "button.titleLabel.alpha = 1;" but i still have a transparent title atm. any recommendations for that?

Comment: The alpha of the button get's applied on top of the on of it's subviews. You will have to set it to 1, then change the alpha of each subview instead.

Comment: how do I access the alpha of other subviews? like backgroundimage and image?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize imageSize = button.imageView.image.size;
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
                                              0.0, - imageSize.width, 0.0, 0.0);
```

left side negative padding for titleLabel. Padding value must be equal to the image width