# image and text width in a UIButton

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

All,

I have an button like this :

[image]

i want to give a little more space between the icon and the text.. Is this possible in Interface Builder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, in IB you can configure options Edge Insets for UIButton.
It's well explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918196/ios-interface-builder-uibutton-title-disappears-when-setting-image), in the [The Lazy Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661229/the-lazy-coder) reply.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, select your button and in the attributes inspector you can set the image insets.

[image]