# can I create a button with text and image together in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uistoryboard

I put a `UIButton` in my storyboard. It looks simple:

[image]

its properties are also simple:

[image]

I wanted to include an image in this button, so that it looks as follows:

```
[image]text
```

but when I put the image name in storyboard:

[image]

the text disappears and all I see is:

[image]

how can I show both things together next to each other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - Interface Builder: UIButton title disappears when setting image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918196/ios-interface-builder-uibutton-title-disappears-when-setting-image)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a white title on white background.

You should see the title if you set `Text Color` back to blue or whatever you wish. For some reason it is different on the screenshots you provided.